# ¿Cómo sumar los elementos de un arreglo?

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de sumar los numeros en un arreglo pero me da resultados
erráticos.

Algunos resultados:

```
suma: -219218260
suma: -560119665
suma: -1820789452
suma: -235808486
suma: 295644714
suma: 334171674
```

Esto es lo que espero obtener:

```
suma: 10
```

Y este es mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int numeros[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    int suma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= (int)(sizeof numeros / sizeof numeros[0]); ++i) {
        suma += numeros[i];
    }

    printf("suma: %d\n", suma);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo envolver esos sizeofs en una macro: `#define getLength(array) sizeof array / array[0]`, de este modo, evitas escribir el sizeof a cada rato..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es simple: usas "<=" en

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (int)(sizeof numeros / sizeof numeros[0]); ++i) {
```

El arreglo tiene 4 elementos, por lo que el `for` se ejecuta con i=0,1,2,3,4.

El arreglo solo tienes elementos desde `numeros[0]` hasta `numeros[3]` y tu accesas `numeros[4]`, que tiene cualquier cosa.

Cambia el "<=" por "<".